# event.target is undefined on a onChange in radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

for example:

```
const Example = () => {
    const letterChange = (e) => {
       console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    }

    return (
       <input 
          type='radio'
          value='X'
          name='radioButton'
          onChange={letterChange}
       />
       <input 
          type='radio'
          value='Y'
          name='radioButton'
          onChange={letterChange}
       />
      )
}
```

The `console.log(e.currentTarget.value)` is returning `'Could not read property "value" of undefined'`.

Would anybody know why? I searched for similar questions but any of them could solve my situation and this is new for me.

In this case, I wouldn't be able to check for the value of the radio button and consequently do nothing. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You seem to be missing a react fragment?

Comment: Once I put the react fragment around the inputs the code works? `e.currentTarget.value` is defined.

Comment: It is working here - https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cookies-9qm7q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: suddenly it has started to work. thanks for all the answers and comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you forget to wrap your element with react fragment I guess.

```
const Example = () => {
  const letterChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='radio'
        value='X'
        name='radioButton'
        onChange={letterChange}
      />
      <input
        type='radio'
        value='Y'
        name='radioButton'
        onChange={letterChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```